# Copy specific cells based on a criteria, to sheets with same label as the criteria in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code for the following task, but I have been struggling a quite a bit.
I have 2 workbooks, wb1 and wb2. 
wb1 has a table with a list of names in column A, then column B-V has the data I want to copy to the sheet with the same name as in column A but in a different book (wb2). The location its pasted to is also dependent on another criteria on the destination sheet in wb2.

so for example in wb1 "John" is the name in A1, switch to wb2, go to the sheet called John, check the criteria on cell A4 of this sheet:
There are 3 criteria which are: Teen, adult or Elder

If Teen, then copy B1 into B97, copy C1 into B135, copy D1 into B147 & B190, copy E4 into B1100

If Adult, then  copy J1 into B97, copy F1 into B135, copy G1 into B147 & B190, copy H4 into B1100

If Elder, then copy B1 into B97, copy C1 into B135, copy D1 into B147 & B190, copy E4 into B1100, copy J1 into B113, copy F1 into B1910, copy G1 into B1473 & B1930, copy H4 into B1190

(The above is just an example, there is a more cells to copy paste than listed above)

This should be looped for all names in column A of wb1.

Below is what macro record gave me, but it doesn't record the criterias. Both workbooks will be open btw.

```
    Sub Summary()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range

    Set wb1= ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A2:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Rng '<---Here is where my first problem is, 
'not sure how to get the excel to switch to the sheet 
'with the same name as in column A then check cell A4 for the criteria'

    If cell.Value = "Teen" Then
    Range("C12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=81
        Range("B97").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("D12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
        Range("B95").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("E12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
        Range("B47").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=63
        Range("B118").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("F12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=48
        Range("B163").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("G12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
        Range("B93").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("H12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
        Range("B105").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=60
        Range("B167").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("I12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
        Range("B141").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("J12").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        Range("B145").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=138
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=51
        Range("B326").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
        Range("B339").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        Range("B317").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        Range("B312").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Range("K12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        Range("B107").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-63
        Range("B49").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate
        Windows("wb2.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=306
        Windows("wb1.xlsx").Activate

    else If cell.Value = "Adult" Then
    '<-----same stuff as above for different cells copy pasted'
    else If cell.Value = "Elder" Then
    '<-----same stuff as above for different cells copy pasted'
 end if
    End Sub
```

Also I don't know if the case function would be useful instead of the If statement here either.

Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT 1**

I changed the code as suggested below

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Measure Templates.xlsx")
    Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A5:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In Rng
        Select Case wb2.Sheets(cell.Text).Range("A4").Value
            Case "Standard Bathroom Template"
            wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("B5").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B97") '<--- I'm getting an error here saying "Object doesn't support this property or method" 
'I assume that this is not the right way to copy paste.
'I looked around but everything online uses a specific sheet name for destination
'which is not the case for me, it should be sheet with same name as in column A 
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("C5").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B117")
                Case "Standard Kitchen Template"
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("B6").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B97")
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("C6").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B117")
                Case "Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T"
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("B7").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B97")
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("C7").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B117")
            End Select
        Next cell

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have updated and added a sheet variable (ws) which points to the relevant sheet for copying (it does not need to be selected or active).

```
    Sub Summary()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Measure Templates.xlsx")
    Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A5:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In Rng
       Set ws=wb2.Sheets(cell.Text)
       Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value
            Case "Standard Bathroom Template"
            wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("B5").Value = ws.Range("B97").Value
            wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("C5").Value = ws.Range("B117").Value
                Case "Standard Kitchen Template"
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("B6").Value = ws.Range("B97").Value
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("C6").Value = ws.Range("B117").Value
                Case "Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T"
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("B7").Value = ws.Range("B97").value
                wb1.Sheet("Summary").Range("C7").Value = ws.Range("B117").Value
            End Select
        Next cell

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, it makes sense, I will give it ago and let you know. Still not sure how I can copy past specific cells? would the following work: `  wb1.Sheet("summary").Range("B2").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B97")  wb1.Sheet("summary").Range("C2").Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B117")  `      and just keep repeating that for all the cells I want to copy paste?

Comment: I've put the new version of the code under **EDIT 1**

Comment: I've updated the code above so let me know how you get on.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm still getting the same error for the same line. I double checked the names match, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Ah, replace `sheet` with `sheets`. Or better use your `sht` variable.

Comment: Oh I see. Also it was copying in reverse, so I switched it around to ws.Range("B97").Value = wb1.Sheets("Summary").Range("B5").Value, and now its working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help